# Using OS Layer styles in SLD format in QGIS 1.8

Tags: sld, qgis-1

I've added OS Landform Parorama information in to QGIS 1.8, i've like to use the OS Layer Styles that are freely downloadable (http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/products/styled-layer-descriptors.html) and come in .sld format.

When i try to load the .sld file through the properties> load styles, the only option i have is to load a .qml file which doesn't appear to be supported.

Is there something i can do to actually load the styles as required?

[image: QGIS Screen Dump]

Nope, only the one option is available for me.

If as Dan says the QGIS styles are currently being worked on then i guess i'll just have to wait!

Comment: The SLD's as they stand can't be used in QGIS.  There is a way to edit these so that QGIS can read them, unfortunately I don't know how to do this (sorry!!).  Hopefully somebody else on here does.  However, I do know that QGIS specific style files (.qml) are being worked on and will be released as soon as they are ready.

Answer (score 1):

In the official QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa, if you try to load a style file through Layer Properties > Load Styles..., the "Load layer properties from style file" dialog will be open:
[image]

As you can see you have **two options (not one)**:

- the first is QGIS Layer Style File (*.qml)
- and the second is SLD File (*.sld).

After choosing your sld and pressing Open button, the dialog will dissapear. Just press Apply button in the previous Layer Properties window and the style will be applied to your layer as expected:
[image]

Your problem is specific to an older QGIS version. **Don't wait**, just go to [gqis.org](http://www.qgis.org) and **update** your software version!

Below, there are some screenshots, to be a reference for you, in case you'll decide to install another QGIS version.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is also possible with QGIS 2 to load sld and save as qml if you can't update (must use) the version you have. You definitely can have more versions of QGIS on your pc if it is needed.